# Calling HTML file that uses javascript and css via ajax.

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am using AJAX to call a html file and the file uses jquery and javascript which I have already called in the page before .But the javascript (and CSS) are not being executed. How can we get my javascript to work.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you provided the only solution I can think of is to use jQuery's `$.get()` more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

`$.get("yourjsfile.js");`//It will request your file and execute it  `$.get("yourcssfile.css");`//Similarly for your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Write them in the `<body/>` instead of `<head/>`. The codes out of `<body/>` will be drop after `jQuery("someSelector").load()`

And jQuery(document).ready() **will not** be executed.